# Problema mostrando mi servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

tengo un problema tratando de mostrar el resultado del servlet. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es agarrar ciertos caracteres que se introducen al formulario, y estos que me despliegue el resultado. Mi problema es cuando quiero desplegar el resultado, solo me aparece una pagina en blanco, que estoy haciendo mal?

O si tambien tengo errores en como capturar los datos indiquenme por favor, muchas gracias a todos por responder.

Les dejo mi codigo y mi servlet:

Pagina JSP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>PAGINA DE EVENTOS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Generador de RFC</h2>
        <h3>Ingresa tus datos: </h3>
        <form method="post" action="rfc">
        
            Nombre:<input type="text" name="textName" id="idNombre">
            <br><br>
            Primer Apellido:<input type="text" name="text1Apellido" id="idApellido">
            <br><br>
            Segundo Apellido:<input type="text" name="text2Apellido" id="idApellido2">
            <br><br>
            Año:<input type="text" name="textAño" id="idAño">
            <br><br>
            Mes:<input type="text" name="textMes" id="idMes">
            <br><br>
            Dia:<input type="text" name="textDia" id="idDia">
            <br><br>
            
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Enviar Datos" /></td>
            
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet rfc

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {



response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

try(    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Generador de RFC:</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

String Nombre = request.getParameter("textName");
        String Apellido = request.getParameter("text1Apellido");
        String Apellido2 = request.getParameter("text2Apellido");
        String Año = request.getParameter("textAño");
        String Mes = request.getParameter("textMes");
        String Dia = request.getParameter("textDia");

       

String rfc;


rfc = Apellido.trim().substring(0,2);
rfc = rfc.concat(Apellido2.trim().substring(0,1));
rfc = rfc.concat(Nombre.trim().substring(0,1));
rfc = rfc.concat(Año.substring(2,4));
rfc = rfc.concat(Mes);
rfc = rfc.concat(Dia);

            out.println("<p>Tu Rfc es: "+rfc.toLowerCase()+"<p>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        
}
}
}
```

Mi web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rfc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rfc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: si no usas algun framework como spring-mvc o struts deberias de poner tu archivo web.xml para ver como declaras el mapeo de servlets

Comment: Gracias por conestar @RuslanLopez ya añadi el web.xml, no lo tenia pero aun asi cuando corro el programa sigue sin aparecerme nada.

Comment: Yo tengo un porblema con el action, cada que escribo 5% de x cosa, simepre me muestra el GET, porque lo tenia en POST pero para ver cual era el problema estoy usando el method=GET, al momento de escribir % me aparece por ejemplo id=5%25+de+algo y la pagina que carga me la pone en blanco y eso no me gusta, ahi quiero saber que es lo que esta ocurriendo, algo no me cuadra, es una pagina de carga y de todos modos guarda los datos en la base pero eso que hace, la pagina de bloque poniendose en blanco no me gusta, algo no cuadra si alguien sabe hagame saber que le falta

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto mi problema, en vez de pasarla por el método doPost fue por processRequest, ademas de añadir web.xml.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).